# Echo PHP string with quotes into input box value

Tags: php, html, variables, input

I have value stored in a PHP variable that contains both single and double quotes. I am trying to echo this into the value of an input box, but the quotes are creating an issue when trying to echo into the value property of the input box.

PHP variable value = 1" Screw for 1' board

I am inserting it into my HTML using the following code:

```
<input value="<?php echo $material['name']; ?>" />
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: and suddenly the question changed. I have no further questions.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The question hasn't changed, at least there is no edit history to indicate that it has changed.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll: the first 5 minutes don't leave a trace.

Comment: yep, used to have addslashes in it! no worries, sorted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addslashes` is the wrong thing to use. Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

`<input value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($material['name']); ?>" />`